# Changing PWD env var in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I wanted to change the env var PWD in Jenkins because the current file path has spaces in it which causes errors. I wanted to place double quotes around this in hopes of resolving this.

PWD: home/user/File Storage
After changing
PWD:home/user/"File Storage"

Did anyone know how to go about changing the PWD?

Comment: You change the path name to not have spaces in it. [POSIX shells set the following environment variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) while using the cd command: PWD -  The current working directory (as set by the cd command). UNIX doea not play well with spaces. You might be able to use by quoting `"${PWD}"`

Comment: `dir("/home/user/File Storage") { ...steps... }`